# Unable to bind click after unbind

Tags: jquery

I have problems trying to bind the click back to the button after I have unbind.

The button will be unbind when there's is change event in the Code text field. The change will  check if there are duplicate in the database. If the there are no duplicate, it will bind back click to the Save button but it's not working.

**The jQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#glaccountssomgr_save_btn').on('click', submitGLAccount);

  $('#glaccountssomgr_acount_code').change(function(event) {

    $('#glaccountssomgr_save_btn').off('click', submitGLAccount);
    var inputCode = $('#glaccountssomgr_acount_code').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'GeneralLedgerAccountsSOMgr', 'action' => 'glaCheckDuplicate', '')); ?>',
      data: {code: inputCode},
      type: 'POST',
      success:function(data)
      {
        if(data)
        {
          var dupResults = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          if(dupResults.isDuplicate)
          { 
            $('#glaccountssomgr_save_btn').off('click');
            alert("The GL Account is already in use. Please use another Code");
            $('#glaccountssomgr_acount_code').focus();
            return false;
      }
      else
      {
        alert("No duplicate");
        //the below does not get call
        $('#glaccountssomgr_save_btn').on('click', submitGLAccount);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      alert("Error in checking GL Account Code. Please try again");
      return false;
    }
  },
  error:function(data)
  {
    alert("Unexpected Error. Please try again");
  }
   });
  });
});

function submitGLAccount()
{
  //performs validation checking and data submission
  alert("I'm here");
}
```

**The Save button**

```
<a href="#" id="glaccountssomgr_save_btn" name="glaccountssomgr_save_btn" data-    
role="button" data-icon="check" data-inline="true" data-ajax="false" data-theme="b"    
data-iconpos="right">Save</a>
```

The Save button will only re-bind again if it's being clicked twice if the focus goes from Code to other form elements.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I would avoid unbinding and rebinding event handlers. Set a toggled variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using bind and unbind:

$('#glaccountssomgr_save_btn').bind('click', submitGLAccount);
$('#glaccountssomgr_save_btn').unbind('click', submitGLAccount);

edited:
your can pass data to the event handler

```
function submitGLAccount(event){
   if(event.data.btnstate=='off'){
         return false;
   }else{
         //continue executing the code
   }
}
$( "button" ).on( "click", {
     btnstate: "off"
}, submitGLAccount);

$( "button" ).on( "click", {
     btnstate: "on"
}, submitGLAccount);
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. But for some strange reasons, it would not get re-bind if there are no duplicates.

Comment: Still not able to re-bind the button using event handler.